# Help with Taylor's theorem

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

[image: Task]

I'm struggling with showing that the third derivative is strongly increasing on the interval. I tried finding the fourth derivative and its roots, but it made me more confused.

I think the inequality has to do something with the error approximation, but I still don't see how to get the expressions $\frac{1}{3}x^3$ and $\frac{112}{81}x^3$.

Comment: You should post what you get as the third derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Write $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \ln(1+x) -\frac{1}{2} \ln(1-x)$. This will help you calculate the third and fourth derivative faster.

Use the fact that $1 \pm x \geq 0$ on your interval.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tips! I'm still stuck on that inequality and the expressions. Do you have a further explanation on that?

Comment: @Mathomat55 By Lagrange there exists some $c \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ such that $$f(x) -P_2(x) =\frac{f^{(3)}(c)}{3!}x^3$$ You need to show that $$\frac{x^3}{3} \leq f(x)-P_2(x) \leq \frac{112}{81}x^3$$ This is equivalent to showing that $$2 \leq f^{(3)}(c) \leq \frac{224}{27}$$

Comment: @N.S.Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it!